Posting an extension of the under review paper on the arXiv
I am a postdoc in mathematics, currently finishing a paper that extends a previous one which has been under review for three months. As I am actively seeking job opportunities, I am considering posting the new paper on arXiv. However, I am concerned that the referee might reject my under-review paper, citing the arXiv version as a better alternative. Could you provide any advice on how to navigate this situation?

You do or do-not. Decisions of the journal are up to them. There is a risk, of course, though it might be considered improper to reject a paper based on a later paper of your own.
First evaluate on your own whether the new paper is a sufficient advance over the current paper to warrant publication. If not, then you might consider combining them yourself, though I doubt that is optimal in your specific case.
However, for purposes of the job market, it probably isn't necessary to show the paper widely, such as arXiv. If you have a section on your CV for "work in progress" you can list it there and say you will make it available on request. That would let you hold off informal publication while still letting it be seen in a job search by a few people.
I also believe that such a work in progress section is very valuable in any job search as it indicates that you are currently active.

Thank you for your answer. Of course, the new paper is a good enough to be published; it is more advance than the under reviewed one. Anyway, I got what you meant. One more question: Is it fine to submit the paper on some journal without posting on the arXiv ?

Posting preprints isn't mandatory. In some (other) fields it is forbidden by most publishers.
